# How to rewrite multiple join statements with aggregate in Django ORM way?

Tags: python, django, orm

I read the [documentation on aggregate](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/db/aggregation/) for Django.

But it does not provide an example of how to retrieve both the aggregate and other related fields.

And certainly not an example where the tables are joined.

I have a working query that I want to be in Django ORM.

```
SELECT SUM(pc.count), p.name, p.art_number from 
packagecontent pc inner join 
product p 
  on pc.product_id = p.id inner join 
package pack 
  on pc.package_id = pack.id 
where pack.pallet_id is not null group by p.id;
```

How do I rewrite this using Django ORM? Not by using the `.raw` function by the way.

Answer (score 0):

In your specific example, you don't need to `aggregate`, but to `annotate` a specific value per object.

Depending on your `Model` names something like this should do what you need:

```
q = (PackageContent.objects
        .filter(package__pallet__isnull=False)
        .values('product__name', 'package__art_number')
        .annotate(models.Sum('count'))
    )
```

Comment: what does annotate mean?